# why git format-patch generates a patch older than the timestamps of reveision range

Tags: git

I tried to generate patches using the following command :

git format-patch M7630AABBQMLZA40701060.. M7630AABBQMLZA40901040 -o patch/

It generated around 2004 patches.
Interestingly first patch points to a  commit dated Jun15 2012.
but the tags used in above command  are   M7630AABBQMLZA40701060 ( tagged on date  OCT30 2012 )
 and  M7630AABBQMLZA40901040 ( tagged on date APR 2013 )

why this command is generating a patch that   doesnot lie in timestamps of revision range?
Also when i applied this patch over the snapshot M7630AABBQMLZA40701060 , GIt am comand is showing patch failed and asking us to solve the conflicts.

Can some one help me here?

Comment: Those tag names are pretty scary -- M7630AABBQMLZA40901040 seems not much better than a full SHA1 like 4881af5b8c658e6c8860571bc288629a3454a040.  But what do you mean by "tagged for <some date>"?  Git tags are simply aliases for SHA1 values.  Specifying <sha1>..<sha1> to `format-patch` tells it to take all the commits "between" those two.  These are based on the commit graph, and need not be in "date order" (eg if I rebase, my older commits may be "on top" of newer ones).  See gitrevisions(7) for more details.

Comment: "tagged for <some date>" means  date on which SHA1 is tagged.

Comment: Ah, so, some (probably automated) process does a `git tag MonstrouslyLongStringWithLettersAndDigits master` or similar, with the long string encoding the date and time at which the `git tag` command is run?  In that case, see @KlasMellbourn's answer.

Comment: Did you mean to have a space between `M7630AABBQMLZA40701060..` and  `M7630AABBQMLZA40901040`?  The included range of commits completely are completely different with and without the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A range of commits can contain commits that are older than the first commit due to rebasing.

A range of commits created using `<rev1>..<rev2>` is defined as the commits that are reachable from <rev2> but excluding those that are reachable from <rev1>. "Reachable" means that a commit can be navigated to using the parent reference that each commit has embedded. So, strictly speaking, a range has nothing to do with dates. See the Git [revisions man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for more details.

During a rebase, the changes made in commits are used to create "copies" of those commits. Those "copies" will have the same author and date as the original commits.

Let's say someone develops something for a long time on a local feature branch, then rebases that feature branch on master and pushes. Then the earliest commits that were rebased will probably have earlier dates than the commits that they were rebased onto.

Comment: Thats correct . Say I generated the patches between  from SHA1.. SHA2. When I apply these generated patches back on SHA1 , I will expect to get back to SHA2 without conflicts . But git am command giving patch applying failed status .. why?

Comment: @kiranbobbu My experience with `git apply` is that they can fail for many reasons. The format of the patch is very important, e.g. on windows they can fail for encoding reasons.

Comment: Thanks Mr Klas.<rev1> is not an ancestor of  <rev2> , hence the  generated patch  list  contains  an ancestor patch  of both  <rev1> and <rev2>. Obviously ancestor patch is older than the <rev1> and <rev2>